# 500 Error while debug = True Django

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error

I have a problem here that are getting me crazy. I have a Django app with Apache and it is throwing a 500 Error in a specific section. The most odd thing is that I have set DEBUG = True in my Django settings. Actually, the app DOES NOT launch the 500 page. I can't see the 500 Error page unless I enter in the "page inspector" of Firefox (or another) and then I see both the page and the error. I can't imagine what is the problem. My Django version is 1.4. Here is my settings.py:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import logging

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

CACHE_BACKEND = 'dummy://'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'teams',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'xxxx',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
SITE_ID = 3
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'j3v+(m*7wb^kbomqz&ask!)7k^%)=e8x9si3s2e-ywg6zonf(u'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
#    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
#    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
    # sentry
    'indexer',
    'paging',
    'sentry',
    'sentry.client',
#    'djcelery',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_beanstalkd',
    'webadmin',
    'teams_test',
    'video',
)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
)
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False
}

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False

GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR = 1
GROUP_TEAMS_ADMIN = 2
GROUP_CLIENT = 3
GROUP_TEAMS_SUPERVISOR = 4

CACHE_BACKEND = 'locmem:///?timeout=1000'
#CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'¬
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 60*5
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = 'teams.'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True

# video app conf
STATIC_URL = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT

# celery conf
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 4
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"

# mysql backend
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
#CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysql://root:root@localhost/teams"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/project/ongoing/'
PATH_ORIGIN_VIDEOS = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'video')
PATH_TO_STORED_VIDEOS =  "/backup/"
URL_TO_STORED_VIDEOS = "/videos/"

# sentry conf
"""
from sentry.client.handlers import SentryHandler
logger = logging.getLogger()
# ensure we havent already registered the handler
if SentryHandler not in map(lambda x: x.__class__, logger.handlers):
    logger.addHandler(SentryHandler())

    # Add StreamHandler to sentry's default so you can catch missed exceptions
    logger = logging.getLogger('sentry.errors')
    logger.propagate = False
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
"""

#import djcelery
#djcelery.setup_loader()
##########################################
# this code must be at the end of this file
##########################################

try:
   from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
   pass
```

And not, the apache error.log does not contain any errors. I hope somebody can help me because I need to run this as fast as I can. It could be very useful that I can see the Debug page of Django to localize the error.

Thanks in advance.

Edition-#1:

These are several parts of my views.py and another files that I was modifying yestesday before the error. The only part I modified is the function finish_phase, it is indicated there.

```
def start_phase(request, phase_id):
    """
    Set phase start date
    """
    phase = get_object_or_404(Phase, pk=int(phase_id))
    cameras = Video.objects.filter(phase=phase)

    ###########################################################################
    ##   BEANSTALK
    ###########################################################################
    # supposed beanstalk concurrency worker is 4
    # TODO: modify django_beanstalkd to set concurrency in settings

    num_workers = 4
    time_to_run = 86400

    not_finished_phases = Phase.objects.exclude(start_date=None).filter(finish_date=None)
    num_cameras_being_recorded = 0
    for not_finished_phase in not_finished_phases:
        num_cameras_being_recorded += Video.objects.filter(phase=not_finished_phase).count()

    free_workers = num_workers - num_cameras_being_recorded
    ## init conversion to a mp4 file
    if free_workers >= len(cameras):
        try:
            beanstalk_client = BeanstalkClient()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        for camera in cameras:
            ##initCapture.delay(camera.slug, camera.url, settings.MEDIA_ROOT,int(phase_id))
            arg = phase_id +' '+settings.PATH_ORIGIN_VIDEOS +' '+camera.slug
            beanstalk_client.call('video.startvlcserver', arg=arg, ttr=time_to_run)
    else:
        response = HttpResponse("<h1>Phase not started</h1>")
        response.write("<p>Camera streams can't be recorded. There are too many cameras working</p>")
        return response
    ##############################################################################

    phase.start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    phase.save()
```

This function start_phase calls the function startvlcserver:

```
def startvlcserver(arg):
    """
    Capture video from an rtsp stream with mp4v codec
    arg format: "phase_id url static_root name"
    """
    phase_id, original_path, name = arg.split(" ")
    Popen("echo  se levanta el servidor: phase: %s %s >> /tmp/startvlcserver.log" % (phase_id, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %H:%M:%S")), shell=True)
    split_command = ['cvlc']
    split_command.append('rtsp://user:password@192.168.2.21/img/media.sav')
    split_command.append("--sout") 
    split_command.append("#transcode{venc=x264{profile=baseline,preset=fast,tune=grain,keyint=25,min-keyint=25,fps=25,bitrate=500},fps=25}:std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=/home/wtelecom/test.mp4}")
    print "#"*30
    print "comando: " 
    print split_command
    sp = Popen(split_command)
    video = Video.objects.get(phase__id=phase_id)
    video.pid = sp.pid
    video.save()
```

Ok, this two functions work fine in my app. The idea is that when I start the phase, an IP camera starts recording. The video stream is transcoded in the function startvlcserver to a mp4 format. But stopping the record requires to stop the vlcserver. Here is the function that stop the phase and the record, and the one which throws the error:

```
def finish_phase(request, phase_id):
    """
    Set phase finish date
    """
    data = {'success':False}
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        phase = get_object_or_404(Phase, pk=int(phase_id))

    # This is the new code added that leaded me to the error:
        cameras = Video.objects.filter(phase=phase)
        #transcoding video
        ###########################################
        # beanstalk
        ###########################################
        for camera in cameras:
            # stop stream capturing
            os.kill(camera.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    # End of the new code

        phase.finish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        phase.save()
        data['success'] = True

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

So let's see if this code helps you all to understand the error and helps me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Have you localised the part of your python code that is throwing the exception? If so can you please post it?

Comment: Does your `local_settings.py` contain any related settings? Also, can you try removing sentry from your `INSTALLED_APPS`? It might interfere with error handling

Comment: Sometimes .pyc files don't automatically get cleared out. If there's a .pyc file on your host, try removing that file, restarting your worker processes and hit the page again.

Comment: One time i had same thing and it was because my 500 page generated error :P. Yeah i had stuff in 500 template that were not in context and this snowballed into error later down the line....

Comment: Ok, here we go:

@Dyrborg I suspect what is the part that is throwing the exception. I edit my post to include this files.

Comment: @sk1p: My local_setting.py does not contain anything related with the error, only EMAIL settings.

Comment: @rjv: The error is an internal server error (500), but I can't localize it.

Comment: @Brandon: I have tried removing my .pyc files and anything happens, the page goes the same.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb: My template is ok, because I had a problem with the same thing few days ago and it showed me the error in the apache error log. Now there is no errors in the log.

Comment: What happens if you run Django without Apache in between? Direct admin.py runserver?

Comment: Nothing happens. The same problem, the same error.